# .NET WebSocket ReceiveAsync not hitting

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

Net.WebSockets to send some data to client which loops `webSocket.SendAsync` in a while loop and but at the time of looping `webSocket.ReceiveAsync` not hitting how we can get call `ReceiveAsync` even when running `SendAsync` in loop?

Here is the code

```
while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
    string jsonStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBuffer);

    while (snuuoitem.playerstatus == "play")
    {
        if (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            await webSocket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, receiveResult.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the way the code is currently structured, `ReceiveAsync` will only be called if `snuuoitem.playstatus` is not `"play"`.

Comment: im looping it for sending some video frames and want to stop or pause with request from client via ReceiveAsync where i need to place the ReceiveAsync in while (snuuoitem.playerstatus == "play") loop? please help

Comment: Resolved! UI Thread was blocked the call ReceiveAsync  solution
byte[] receiveBuffer;
while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
     Task.Run(async()=>{ await ProcessNewTask(receiveResult,receiveBuffer});
}